# Inactive and scared inside, rambunctious playful outside

Tags: dogs, behavior, fear

[image]

We just got a new puppy 2 days ago. Since we got her she has barely moved. Inside she lays around scared but outside she is a completely different dog. She plays she runs but she is still very shy.

She was outside in a pen since she was born, so I know this is a new experience for her.

She won’t walk around the house I have to carry her everywhere and even carry her outside. We have an older dog that she loves but won’t follow her around like I was hoping she would.

Is there anything that I could possibly do to help the transition from dirty pen to loving home?

Comment: Sorry about the pine cone she loves to chew on them while outside so I brought a couple inside thinking it would help. She did chew it but hasn’t moved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first instinct of bringing something positive from outside to the inside is very good. But I think you should stop carrying her.

1. Put her water and food so close to her that she can eat and drink without moving.
2. Sit close to her for 10 minutes but ignore her at first. If she comes to you, reward her with your voice and pet her. Then offer her a toy she likes and play with her. Gradualy move your play away from her blanket.
3. Hold some pieces of sausage or cheese in your hand. It has to be a scent she cannot ignore. If she moves her head towards you, give her one piece, then move a tiny distance away from her. Let her move towards you and reward her for it.
4. Don't carry her outside. Carry her to the door, go outside and call her.

You should make the typical "play bow" gesture. Dogs  jump with just their front legs stretched far forwards. As a human you should bow forward, clap hands in front of you and nod to her. See an example on youtube: https://youtu.be/fzAX65hpyXY

5. When she starts to trust you, let her stand up and gently push her forward. Reward her for every few steps she takes with sausage or dog treats